# In PHP, IMAP Functions, what are the functions that download the attached files ? (even if we don't explicitely want to download them)

Tags: php, imap

In PHP, IMAP Functions, what are the functions that download the attached files.
I only want to download attached files if needed. I want to save bandwidth, but maybe some functions download them to get their information, or the structure of the email ?
If I have an attachment of 2G, I don't want to download it, but want all the same to get the other part of the email (text parts, information about the email structure,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`imap_fetchbody`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) and [`imap_fetchstructure`](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchbody.php). Messages with attachments are multi-part messages; you can tell `imap_fetchbody` which part you want to fetch.

Comment: I know that imap_fetchbody downloads the specified part of the email, so it downloads attachment if needed. But does imap_fetchstructure downloads the different parts in order to get the email structure (including the attachment files) ? (it's probably an obvious answer that I'll get, but I just want to be sure that I don't use twice as much bandwidth than needed)

Comment: @Ced No, the server determines the parts and send only the metadata.